# How to put text on the left bottom corner of the img, and how to let it stay there when the screen is resized?

Tags: html, css

I am new to programming and I want to make a website where I want to  put a text to the left bottom corner of an image. How to put it there and how to let it stay there when the screen is resized. And is my code ok ? or should I change something ?
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/PkriszP/whzmd5u6/4/)

```css
.flex{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.container-one a{
  position: relative;
}
img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box-one{
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  
}
.container-one:hover .box-one {
   opacity: 1;
}
 span{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: red;
   float:
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<div class="container-one">
<a href="#dog">
<img src="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/g_collection_png/standard/256x256/dog.png">
<div class="box-one">
  <span>dog</span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="container-two">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with very simple css code.

Try this:

```
.box-one span {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position: absolute` with the bottom-left alignment to your `.box-one span` which is your text element

```
.box-one span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```css
.flex {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container-one a {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-one {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.box-one span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.container-one:hover .box-one {
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="container-one">
    <a href="#dog">
      <img src="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/g_collection_png/standard/256x256/dog.png">
      <div class="box-one">
        <span>dog</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container-two">
  </div>
</div>
```